# Create Salesforce Records from JSON response

Tags: apex, json

I am looking on button click to create a few contacts from the JSON response I receive from by API request. As it stands I have set up the button and it is parsing the JSON string back to a variable.

```
global with sharing class PullDirectors {

   webservice static String getDirectors(String regNumber) {
      //test
      //C_House CH = new C_House();
      C_House.CompaniesHouseCalloutsResponse CHresp = new C_House.CompaniesHouseCalloutsResponse();
      C_House.CompaniesHouseCalloutsRequest CHreq = new C_House.CompaniesHouseCalloutsRequest();
      C_House.CompaniesHouse.OfficerList CH = new C_House.CompaniesHouse.OfficerList();
      JSON2ApexX.Items item = new JSON2ApexX.Items();
      // On success, return a message to the calling program.
      String test;
      test = CHreq.getRequestOfficersList(regNumber);

      System.debug('CH : ' + test);
      return test;
   }

}
```

I have also used a tool to pull the seperate class to build out the variables from the response.

```
public class JSON2ApexX {

    public class JSON2Apex {
        public Integer inactive_count;
        public Integer total_results;
        public String kind;
        public Integer active_count;
        public String etag;
        public Links links;
        public List<Items> items;
        public Integer start_index;
        public Integer resigned_count;
        public Integer items_per_page;
    }

    public class Address {
        public String postal_code;
        public String locality;
        public String address_line_1;
        public String address_line_2;
        public String region;
    }

    public class Date_of_birth {
        public Integer month;
        public Integer year;
    }

    public class Links_Z {
        public Officer officer;
    }

    public class Address_U {
        public String postal_code;
        public String address_line_1;
        public String premises;
        public String locality;
    }

    public class Links {
        public String self;
    }

    public class Address_V {
        public String locality;
        public String address_line_2;
        public String postal_code;
        public String address_line_1;
    }

    public class Items {
        public Address address;
        public String nationality;
        public String name;
        public String appointed_on;
        public Links_Z links;
        public String officer_role;
        public String country_of_residence;
        public Date_of_birth date_of_birth;
        public String occupation;
        public String resigned_on;
    }

    public class Address_Y {
        public String postal_code;
        public String locality;
        public String address_line_1;
    }

    public class Address_Z {
        public String region;
        public String locality;
        public String postal_code;
        public String address_line_1;
    }

    public class Address_W {
        public String postal_code;
        public String region;
        public String country;
        public String address_line_1;
        public String address_line_2;
        public String locality;
        public String premises;
    }

    public class Officer {
        public String appointments;
    }

    public class Address_X {
        public String postal_code;
        public String locality;
        public String country;
        public String address_line_1;
        public String address_line_2;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }

}
```

I guess my question is where do I go from here, this is my first time using JSON in salesforce.

Also the JSON response is below:

```
{
  "total_results": 5,
  "inactive_count": 0,
  "kind": "officer-list",
  "etag": "d73856cd714b6ebc4c2cad780a9eb1167c051352",
  "items_per_page": 35,
  "links": {
    "self": "/company/08004359/officers"
  },
  "start_index": 0,
  "active_count": 2,
  "resigned_count": 3,
  "items": [
    {
      "address": {
        "address_line_1": "Sutherland House",
        "premises": "2nd Floor",
        "address_line_2": "70-78 West Hendon Broadway",
        "locality": "London",
        "postal_code": "NW9 7BT",
        "country": "England"
      },
      "links": {
        "officer": {
          "appointments": "/officers/5dBgxqK6s5gZCN_ujFIQ3k_sGKk/appointments"
        }
      },
      "name": "COHEN, Benjamin Jacob",
      "officer_role": "director",
      "appointed_on": "2015-12-10",
      "nationality": "British",
      "country_of_residence": "England",
      "date_of_birth": {
        "year": 1984,
        "month": 1
      },
      "occupation": "Director"
    },
    {
      "occupation": "Director",
      "date_of_birth": {
        "year": 1975,
        "month": 5
      },
      "nationality": "American",
      "appointed_on": "2016-08-05",
      "country_of_residence": "Usa",
      "officer_role": "director",
      "name": "WEISER, Yekutiel Yehuda Benjamin",
      "links": {
        "officer": {
          "appointments": "/officers/s_SJanjN94plC5v2LnyyOWdiUto/appointments"
        }
      },
      "address": {
        "postal_code": "NW9 7BT",
        "country": "England",
        "address_line_1": "Sutherland House",
        "locality": "London",
        "premises": "2nd Floor",
        "address_line_2": "70-78 West Hendon Broadway"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "STERNGOLD, Esther",
      "links": {
        "officer": {
          "appointments": "/officers/3ULDNVmQlgZK7rvwoWXJ7YDDGNE/appointments"
        }
      },
      "address": {
        "address_line_1": "35-37 Brent Street",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "locality": "London",
        "postal_code": "NW4 2EF",
        "premises": "Foframe House"
      },
      "occupation": "Consultant",
      "date_of_birth": {
        "month": 8,
        "year": 1962
      },
      "country_of_residence": "England",
      "resigned_on": "2012-09-19",
      "nationality": "British",
      "appointed_on": "2012-03-23",
      "officer_role": "director"
    },
    {
      "officer_role": "director",
      "nationality": "American",
      "appointed_on": "2012-03-26",
      "country_of_residence": "United States Of America",
      "resigned_on": "2014-04-10",
      "date_of_birth": {
        "year": 1978,
        "month": 11
      },
      "occupation": "Executive",
      "address": {
        "postal_code": "NW4 2EF",
        "premises": "Foframe House",
        "locality": "London",
        "address_line_1": "35-37 Brent Street",
        "country": "England"
      },
      "name": "WAJSFELD, Shaya",
      "links": {
        "officer": {
          "appointments": "/officers/ua4tQuACZgnozd0mDAQxkyBiOno/appointments"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "address": {
        "locality": "London",
        "address_line_1": "35-37 Brent Street",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "postal_code": "NW4 2EF",
        "premises": "Foframe House"
      },
      "links": {
        "officer": {
          "appointments": "/officers/824nhQl7PjZyL79H9OC5kiAJI8A/appointments"
        }
      },
      "name": "WEISER, Yekutiel Yehuda Benjamin",
      "date_of_birth": {
        "year": 1975,
        "month": 5
      },
      "occupation": "Company Director",
      "officer_role": "director",
      "country_of_residence": "Usa",
      "resigned_on": "2016-08-04",
      "appointed_on": "2012-03-23",
      "nationality": "American"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It will be better you could complete this trailhead [Apex Integration Overview](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_callouts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a skeleton that you could expand on that assumes the `CHreq.getRequestOfficersList` returns the JSON that your `JSON2ApexX` can then parse and map to `Account` objects to insert:

```
String jsonString = CHreq.getRequestOfficersList(regNumber);
JSON2ApexX.JSON2Apex parsed = JSON2ApexX.parse(jsonString);

Account[] inserts = new Account[] {};
for (JSON2ApexX.Items item : parsed.items) {
     inserts.add(new Account(
             Name = item.name,
             BillingStreet = item.address.address_line_1,
             BillingPostalCode = item.address.postal_code,
             ...
             ));
}
insert inserts;
```

One hard part is mapping the data fields from the JSON to the available standard Account fields. (You could also choose to add your own custom fields to Account.)